# Simple Query to List SSRS Names, Create and Modify Dates

Tags: t-sql, reporting-services

I'm looking for a simple way to script out a list all of the names, create_date, and modify_date fields for my SSRS reports. Results to look some thing like this:

```
name            create_date                 modify_date
========================================================
MySSRSReport    2014-12-12 13:01:32.803     2014-12-16 21:39:03.553
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run this query against your SQL Server reporting database. By default, it is named `ReportServer`.

```
SELECT Name AS name
    ,CreationDate AS create_date
    ,ModifiedDate AS modify_date
FROM [Catalog]
WHERE [Type] = 2 -- Report.
```

Comment: Just to add to this, Microsoft does not [document or support querying the report Catalog table](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/60dd3392-42d8-4dc4-b8e6-15e9aeaad29e/table-explaination-for-dbocatalog-table-in-reportserver-database), so you may see different fields/changes between report server versions.